# Jquery calling PHP function on jquery ajax success

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to call a php function on jquery ajax call.When i tried to do this i get function not defined error on php function

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"x.php?z=" + id,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data)
        {

          <?php xcz();  ?>
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you just send back the proper data? You're already server-side during the POST, just echo back the proper data so you can access it in the success function.

Comment: @TheZ:xcz() has a select statement which pulls data from database.

Comment: @user1415759 And? You should be able to access it in the `x.php` file since it's server-side.

Comment: @TheZ:xcz() is in index.php and my above jquery ajax function is also in index.php

Comment: @user1415759 PHP files can call functions in other PHP files. I just don't understand why you'd want to have this setup `client->server->client->server->client` when you can go (at worst) `client->server->server->client`. Think about the flow of data.

Comment: @TheZ:I'm not clear but that you,you've been helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"x.php?z=" + id,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data)
        {

          anotherFunction();
        }
    });

function anotherFunction(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"anotherFile.php",
        cache:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
              //do something else;
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: :In another function,i've a select statement which will pull data from database.

Comment: ok but I can't use mysql code in JS. Just put the select statement in "anotherfile.php" (is the one called in anotherFunction()). In php you can return the data in json format and do what you want in jquery's success event

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. PHP and javascript run on different computers. PHP runs on the server, and javascript runs in the browser. At the time the javascript is being executed, that server has already executed the PHP code, and has sent that the the browser.

The only way you can achieve such a thing is making an additional Ajax request.

Comment: :How do i make ajax request ?

Comment: Exactly how did you do, inside the success{} put another .ajax({}) call

Comment: @Kreker:How to call another callback function

Comment: @Kreker:$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"x.php?z=" + id,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
.ajax({
          <?php xcz();  ?> 
        } })
    });  Is this the ,how i do it?

Comment: look at my answer. I think is ok

Comment: @Kreker:Updated my answer to you post.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Because jQuery (javascript) runs on client side, php runs on server side.

When page loaded on browser, php's job is finished.

You can call just javascript's function like this approach.